# How to clue actors with distinctive names (without giving away who they are)?

Tags: cryptic-clues, puzzle-creation

I've found myself needing to fill a gap in a cryptic crossword with a word that happens to be the surname of an actor. However the surname they have is very distinctive.

As an example, let's say the actor was John Malkovich, and for the sake of argument the wordplay part is something do with an anagram of his name, maybe 'Havoc Milk'.

Is it sufficient to just use their first name as the definition part:

> John causing havoc with spilt milk (9)

Or if is more standard to use 'actor'?

> Actor causing havoc with spilt milk (9)

Or could I even get away with using one of their famous (or even obscure) film roles?

> [Virus](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0118880/characters/nm0000518) played havoc with spilt milk (9)

I'm not familiar with what standards different setters have for these situations, so I'm unsure how to do this well... I want to opt for the latter one, as it fits a theme in the crossword but seems the least standard.

Answer (score 2):

The first one could be sufficient as far as the explicitly asked question goes.  That is, "John" would be an acceptable definition. (although it works better with slightly less common names.)

However, I don't really like the wordplay.  There's nothing to indicate HAVOC as anagram fodder.  "Playing havoc with spilt milk" is better, but it still isn't perfect in that "with" is usually a join, so you end up cluing "HAVOC* + MILK*" -- Which would be fine if each anagram made up a part of the word, like VACHO + KILM (which is a nonsense example) What you want to clue is "[HAVOC + MILK]*". - that is, join the fodder into one unit then anagram it.

Personally, I think the last one is too obscure for most people.  BUT if it was part of a theme puzzle on Con-Air, where you also had CAGE and CUSACK as answers in the grid, it would probably be perfectly fine.

Maybe try something along the lines of "John playing havoc with milk" but the surface reading isn't as nice.